# Create Dataframe from unknown number of Series pandas

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a list of (user defined) objects known as "Instrument Measurements". These, have a title, accessible by `Instrument_Measurement.name` and a series of data accessible  by `Instrument_Measurement.data` (both user defined methods).

These "Instrument Measurement" objects are items in a list called `list_instr_objects`. The number of items ("Instrument Measurements") changes/cannot be hard-coded.

I need to create a Dataframe with column titles `Instrument_Measurement.name` for each "Instrument Measurement" and data for that column of `Instrument_Measurement.data` for that respective "Instrument Measurement".

I'm trying to do this by creating a dictionary of these objects and then converting that to a Dataframe:

```
from collections import defaultdict
testdict = defaultdict(list)

for i in range(len(list_instr_objects)):
    testdict[list_instr_objects[i].name].append(list_instr_objects[i].data)
```

This doesn't work though, only the first data entry for each instrument is kept and the entries come out in a seemingly random order. I think this is because I'm passing a Series to the dictionary where I should be passing a list, but I can't think how else to do it/how to fix this.

Any thoughts?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The columns would definitely be in an arbitrary order (as dictionaries do not have orders): is that a problem? The other issue is that you don't want to append it to a list, you want to just set it as `testdict[list_instr_objects[i].name] = list_instr_objects[i].data` (and it doesn't have to be a defaultdict, just a dictionary)

Comment: Unfortunately after using just a dictionary and not appending to list, I'm still getting the same issue of having only the first element. Unfortunately I do require the order to be preserved so I'll look into a non-dictionary based method. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use OrderedDict to keep the order and use below code to generate the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

testdict = OrderedDict()

for i in range(len(list_instr_objects)):
    testdict[list_instr_objects[i].name] = (list_instr_objects[i].data)

combined_data = pd.DataFrame(testdict)
```